# Entries won't show up on template page for flask app

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm having trouble getting my database entries from a form to show up on my output page. I think it's my flask-sqlalchemy query, but I have gotten nothing from the docs. There is no error message or traceback. Code below:

Route for form page:

```
@app.route('/thing', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def thing():
    form = TForm()
    return render_template(
        'thing.html',
        form=form,
        page_title = 'Add It', 
        form_submit_label = 'Add Entry')
```

Route for form action:

```
@app.route('/addthing', methods=['POST'])
def add_thing():
    form = TForm(request.form)
    filename = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
        cover = request.files['cover']
        if cover and allowed_file(cover.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(cover.filename)
            cover = cover.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return cover
        t = Thing(
            title = request.form['title'],
            genre = request.form['genre'],
            summary = request.form['summary'],
            cover = cover
        )
        db.session.add(t)
        db.session.commit()
     flash('New entry was successfully posted')
     return redirect(url_for('thinglist'))
```

Route for template:

```
@app.route('/thinglist', methods=['GET'])
def thinglist():
    thing_entries = Thing.query.all()
    # below thing_entries works, but it was just a way to test
    # thing_entries = [{'title': 'No where fast', 'genre': ['red', 'blue'], 'summary': 'I love trains'},
    # {'title': 'No why', 'genre': ['yellow', 'blue'], 'summary': 'I love lamp'},
    # {'title': 'where fast', 'genre': ['red', 'green'], 'summary': 'I love cats'}]
    return render_template(
        'thinglist.html',
        thing_entries=thing_entries,
        page_title = 'Thing List')
```

Thing List Template

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% for entry in thing_entries %}

<article>
    <div>
        <div>
            <img src="{{ entry.cover }}" alt="Cover for {{ entry.title }}" /> 
        </div>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li class="">{{ entry.title }}</li>
                <li class=""><strong>Genre: </strong>{{ entry.genre }}</li>
                <li class=""><strong>Summary: </strong>{{ entry.summary|truncate( 30, true ) }}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>

{% else %}

<div class="no-entries">Nothing</div>

{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I have tried many variations of the Thing.query.all() line, such as

```
Thing.query.filter_by(id=thing_id).all() ==> doesn't work
Thing.query.filter(thing_id) ==> doesn't work
Thing.query.get(thing_id) ==> doesn't work
```

I just don't understand. Thank you for the help.

Comment: This is potentially very redundant inquiry, but have you checked that there's anything *in* the database? Open a Python interpreter, import the database and the model, and run `Thing.query.all()` there. Does that return anything?

Comment: You were right. How could there be nothing? I've been submitting the form and I've been getting the 'New entry was successfully posted' message without any problem. I thought that when you commit the entries it adds it to the database? I'm so confused.

Comment: `db.session.add` and `db.session.commit` will add the model to the database, yes. Must be that the code isn't reaching that point, then.

Comment: Then, how do I find out what's wrong? I'm not getting any errors and I'm kind of just stumbling around at this point. All the applicable code (other than the model and form) is in the above text. I put a random "print 'success'" after the db text and it printed in the command line.